# SSH parameter help on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, script, ssh, sh

I have a variable setup like this:

```
SSH_EXEC="ssh -X -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-$$ -o ControlPersist=60"
```

The parameter in question is the `-X`, because if I then call this command within my local script

`$SSH_EXEC user@server "./server_script.sh $aFile"`

which in a nutshell does the following:

```
if [ -e /path/"$1".name ] || [ -e /path/"$1" ]
then 
   do something
else
   error
   echo "/path/"$1".name"
   exit
fi
```

Everything works!  But if I replace `-X` with `-t`, my `server_script` fails to the `else` on the test.  I'd prefer not use x11, but I'm not sure what the difference is that is causing it to fail in one instance, and pass in the other.

**EDIT**

So I just did more troubleshooting and decided to echo the value of `/path/$1.name` on the server and it is garbled junk.  If my `$aFile` name happened to be `hello.name` the result of the echo shows `.nameello` and also rids the beginning of the path when I use `-t` in place of `-X`.

What could be causing the corruption of my variables?

Comment: You aren't using X11. In one case you enable X11 forwarding, in the other you force a pseudo-tty to be created. Also, your code "in a nutshell" doesn't contain enough (not even the echo) to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: @Hasturkun I've modified my above example a little more.  What I have "in a nutshell" is where my code fails.  It's right at the beginning of a long server script.

Comment: It's sort of a silly suggestion, but what happens if you pipe the output from your ssh command through `xxd` or similar?

Comment: @Hasturkun not a silly question!  I don't know what `xxd` is, could you elaborate?

Comment: Hex dump. I'm guessing there are control characters in your output, eg. a `^H` (backspace) would delete the characters before it in shell output. Would be visible in a hex dump. In this case, my psychic powers tell me it's a `^M` (Carriage return) at the end of `$aFile`

Comment: Do you think that doing a `-o SendEnv $aFile` would ensure the variable is properly transferred as an argument to the server script?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31726/discussion-between-hasturkun-and-nkon)

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close the thread since it clearly relates to programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$aFile` probably has a trailing [Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character, causing the terminal to return to the start of the line when encountered.

As an example, the following:

```
echo "/path/"hello^M".name"
```

outputs:

```
/.namehello
```

This sort of thing might happen due to a shell script with DOS [line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_endings), causing a line like

```
aFile = "hello"
```

to be interpreted as

```
aFile = "hello"^M
```

If that's the case, you should be able to convert your script to use Unix line endings using the `dos2unix` utility.